# Adding a line break inside an element's value between two variables

Tags: php, html

I'm attempting to add a line break between two variables in the value of an `input` field.

I've tried the script below (using the html tag `<br>`), however the value of the `input` field displays as `4 <br> body` (rather than a line break between the two variables).

```
<?php
$variable1 = '4';
$variable2 = 'body';

echo'
<input type="checkbox" value="'.$variable1.' <br> '.$variable2.'">
';
?>
```

The reason I need a line break between the two variables is that further on in the script, the value of the `input` field is entered into a database and later on displayed (using `SELECT`) and the space between the variables is required.

Is there a pure `PHP` solution to include a line break between the variables (rather than using `HTML`)?

Comment: This is not valid in HTML

Comment: Could someone please explain the downvote?

Comment: question is: why do you want to add a line break in an input? That's just going to mess it up really and making it an invalid input. (P.s.: Not my dv)

Comment: If you really want to do this, then do `echo'<input type="checkbox" value="'.$variable1.'" <br> "'.$variable2.'">';` which will produce this in HTML source `<input type="checkbox" value="4" <br> "body">` but on screen will be a different result.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The value of the checkbox is inserted into a database and on another page, I use `SELECT` to get the stored value from the database and display it. `$variable1` and `$variable2` relate to different things (take an email subject and email message for example) and it would be confusing (for the viewer) to display them next to each other.

Comment: then drop the <br> tag. You're probably looking to use a `name` attribute, no? yes? or just concatenate them with a space between.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Would that display `$variable2` under `$variable1`?

Comment: No it wouldn't. Yet, something like this `echo'<input type="checkbox" value="'.$variable1. " " . $variable2.'">';` producing `<input type="checkbox" value="4 body">` yes? that's only in source though, nothing on screen. You can't put line breaks in inputs. Or, use 2 checkboxes of the same group name if you want to do this. That's all I can think of. Edit: Hold on, I think I know what may work.

Comment: what about this `echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$variable1. " " . $variable2.'">'.$variable1.' <br> '.$variable2.'';` and source `<input type="checkbox" value="4 body">4 <br> body` and will echo those on 2 lines. You may have to alter that a bit for the value. Unsure what you're looking to use for the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111303/discussion-between-the-codesee-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion, the solution to the question turned out to use `\n` for a line break in HTML source and on screen being:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$variable1. "\n" . $variable2.'">'.$variable1.' <br> '.$variable2.'';
```

Resulting in:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="4
body">4 <br> body
```

and then using `nl2br()` on display.

---

If you wish to use PHP's [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) constant, the syntax would be:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$variable1.PHP_EOL.$variable2.'">'.$variable1.' <br> '.$variable2.'';
```

or as `\r\n`:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$variable1. "\r\n" . $variable2.'">'.$variable1.' <br> '.$variable2.'';
```

However, PHP's `PHP_EOL` constant will cover cross-platform OS's such as DOS/Mac/Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Storing HTML in a database is *normally* a terrible idea. (There are some exceptions, e.g. with CMS's.)

If you must, your task is to ensure the `<br>` is retained in the value but not parsed as HTML, thus invalidating your page and likely confusing the browser's renderer.

The solution is to encode it:

```
&lt;br&gt;
```

Comment: Well a `br` is not a linebreak character; it's an HTML instruction to do a linebreak. `echo "\r\n"` will echo a pure break in PHP, but that's not what your question asks (which I've answered.)